# UiTextView with edge to edge exclusion path cause all the text to disappear

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a `UITextView` and i want to add a custom `UIView` to it and make the text flow above and below like so:

```
+----------------+
|------txt-------|
|                |
|     UIView     |   
|                |
|------txt-------|
|----------------|
|----------------|
+----------------+
```

I tried to achieve this by adding an exclusion path that has the `UITextView` width and the `UIView`'s height like so:

```
CGRect exclusionFrame=CGRectMake(0, 
                                CGRectGetMinY(element.frame),
                                self.textView.textContainer.size.width,
                                CGRectGetHeight(element.frame)); 
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths=@[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:exclusionFrame]];
```

But for some reason if the exclusion path's width equal the textView's width all the text below the `UIView`  (aka `element`) disappear. When i reduce the exclusion path's width by one the text appear with a one letter column next to the `UiView` like this:

```
+----------------+
|------txt-------|
|a               |
|d     UIView    |   
|e               |
|------txt-------|
|----------------|
|----------------|
+----------------+
```

Why can't i create a edge to edge exclusion path and is there a way around this predicament?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being the storyboard. I took only the UiTextView out of the view and initialized it programmatically that seemed to solve the problem:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.textView=[[UITextView alloc] init];
    self.textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];

    NSDictionary* views = @{@"textView": self.textView};
    NSArray* vContrains=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-50-[textView]-50-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:views];
    NSArray* hContrains=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-50-[textView]-50-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:vContrains];
    [self.view addConstraints:hContrains];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same issue, fortunately I'm just putting in \n\r\n\r 's to solve it. Cheating I know but it works.

Comment: This is my solution as well for now. Isn't there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`

may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue with swift, the solution comes after reading a different thread with switch and `objective-c` example.

I have an UITextView with `Scrolling Enabled = true`. 
With no scrolling, I have not a problem, but I need this feature.

1. I used the standard setup, with scrolling enable = true

```
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: myview.frame)
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path]
self.textView.addSubview(myview)
```

2. And I disable the scroll when I change the UITextView text

```
func setText( message: String ) {
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.text = message
    textView.isScrollEnabled = true
}
```

This solves my problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles across this thread in the future:

I had a similar error, where my text disappeared when using exclusion paths. I could fix it by using TextKit1 rather than TextKit2:

```swift
let useTextKit2 = false
let textView = UITextView(usingTextLayoutManager: useTextKit2)
```

However, I couldn't fix the bug where the words are split into single characters independent of lineBreakMode. This seems to be an underlying error of TextKit. Even in Apple's newest sample code from WWDC 2022, this error still occurs:

[Link to Apple's documentation on enriching text in text views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/textkit/enriching_your_text_in_text_views)