# UITextView scroll to end automatically issue

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout, uistoryboard

I have set auto layout constraints to my text view and now when I rotate the device app sometimes automatically scrolls text view to the end of content. For example in case when I have many words in the textview and the content size is bigger then text view, then I see not a top word but see instead bottom words. And never see the First word of text.

[image]

As you can see the text is cut off on the visible first line. Because it scrolled. But I just want to see top of text view not a bottom.

Comment: In didAutoRotateInterfaceOrientation, try changing textview's contentOffset property as per orientation.

Comment: @Mrunal, but it sometimes also works the same with a rotation. For example in my table view. Just when I scrolled table view seems text views redrawn then and it looks good. But at start text view seems automatically scrolls down.

Comment: Can you please upload screenshot, just to get better idea?

Comment: hm, seems it works incorrect times to times. or maybe I get different length of text. But after rotation it 100% scroll down and show bottom text.

Comment: @Mrunal update with scenes shot. So the cutting appear because the first word in text view upper then that we see, so i can scroll up manually and will see first word but after rotation it scroll view down.

Comment: Print frame of UITextView for both in Portrait and in Landscape.

Comment: @Mrunal, the same like here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168268/uitextview-text-not-showing-top-lines-after-rotation-in-ios7)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67245/discussion-between-mrunal-and-matrosov-alexander).

Comment: @Mrunal, I've tried change contentOffset but it does not work(